# Cannot excute commands with sudo

Tags: login, sudo, password-recovery

I forgot my user password. After resetting it using `passwd menuka` from recovery mode, I tried the new password in the terminal to run commands with `sudo`, but it keeps failing when I try the new password.

when I run the `id` command I got this.

```
$ id
uid=1000(menuka) gid=1000(menuka) groups=1000(menuka),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Another issue is if I lock the computer and try to unlock the  computer, the new password doesn't work. It works when I start the machine only.

I assumed the old password was cached in the system. I tried deleting password for the user menuka and updating it. But no success.

Can anybody help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Are there any special (e.g. punctuation, accented) characters in your password? What are the keyboard layout and language settings for your desktop session? What is the exact error message from `sudo`?

Comment: I use Uppercase, lowercase, numbers and @ charactor in the password. Keyboard layout is English(UK). when I try password it says sorry, try again.no error messages..

Comment: You can always use a grub prompt or a live dvd to reset the password to set it to a numbers/chars only password. And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: +1 to @Rinzwind's suggestion - the @ character may be the culprit if your session has somehow got set to US keyboard layout

Comment: yes, when swith the keyboard layout, password started to work. I had to change it to UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the keyboard layout as mentioned on the above comments solved the problem.

Comment: If you see that a suggestion from commenter you should report them back that it worked. Because they spent time on your problem and deserve one or two upvote. Don't they?

Comment: I had upvoted the comments that were helpful

Comment: I mean upvoting the answer or asking to answer the question as those worked for you.